# How to mute on Galaxy s2 on android 4.1.2

Tags: settings, mute

Have just updated software to android 4.1.2 and whereas before one went to settings - sound - and had options mute vibrate so you could mute the phone this new version does not offer that.  How do I mute the phone now?

Answer (score 1):

Just hit the volume buttons in the main screen and you should be able to move to silent mode.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Initially I had no idea what you were referring to - being a bit dim, but if one touches the top of the screen and 'slides' down it displays settings which include 'Mute'.  So, many, many, thanks - this OAP got there in the end!!